# Aspose Words .NET: MergeField TableStart name truncated by .NET API, Node#GetText()

Tags: .net, aspose

We have a MergeField in a .doc template

TableStart:ProjectPersonRoles

When browsing the tables using the .NET API on this particular Node GetText() returns

TableStart:ProjectPerso

In the same document other MergeFields which are in fact TableStart work fine, only this one fails.

Any known issues applicable?

Thank you.

Kind regards

Bart

Answer (score 0):

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose. First of all, I would recommend you to download the [latest version of Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) and test the issue with that. If it doesn't resolve your issue then our team will have to investigate the issue in detail. And for that matter, we might require the input document(s) and other related material. So, it would be better if you report such technical issues in [Aspose.Words Forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Our development/Support teams would be able to resolve your issue.